# Condensed matter physics: the concept of holes

Tags: solid-state-physics

Is it possible to see an analogy between the holes and positron particle behavior? The holes are particles that behave oppositely to the electron in current conduction.

So it is not the electron which the same behavior of holes. Positron is just the antiparticle of the electron that has same positive charge. In what way do these two concepts differ ?

Answer (score 2):

The *hole* is a quasiparticle, i.e. something that behaves *as if*, to some extent, there were a particle instead of the system that we are dealing with.

The *positron* is a **real** particle, that exists on its own.

The hole only exists in the presence of other electrons, it cannot exists on its own. This is because a hole is the *absence* of an electron, but the concept of of "absence" only makes sense if there are electrons around. The hole "moves" only because a neighbouring electron fills the vacancy and the hole therefore shifts.

Here's a sketch:

[image]

Hopefully from this you can appreciate that the hole can only "exist" and "move" when there are several electrons around, but it could not do it on its own.

A positron can exist and move on its own, it's real.